# Как забрать текст из блока по которому кликнули?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть неопределенное кол-во таких блоков:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-name">Коробка 1</div>
  <div class="box-description">Коробка 1 Коробка 1 Коробка 1</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-name">Коробка 2</div>
  <div class="box-description">Коробка 2 Коробка 2 Коробка 2</div>
</div>
```

При клике на любой из блоков **box** нужно получить текст из **box-name** и **box-description** и записать в переменные **a** и **b**

Как это сделать с помощью jquery?

Comment: Вообще никаких идей?

Comment: @Igor типа так $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').click(function () {
        let a = $('.box-name').text
    });
});

Comment: попробуйте определить по какому из 2-х (в примере 2-а) блоков вы кликнули

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> типа так `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.box').click(function () { let a = $('.box-name').text }); });`

Почти.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let a, b;
  $('.box').click(function() {
    a = $(this).find('.box-name').text();
    b = $(this).find('.box-description').text();
    console.log('name:', a);
    console.log('description:', a);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-name">Коробка 1</div>
  <div class="box-description">Коробка 1 Коробка 1 Коробка 1</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-name">Коробка 2</div>
  <div class="box-description">Коробка 2 Коробка 2 Коробка 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему-то не работает, в консоле "ƒ (e){return _(this,function(e){return void 0===e?k.text(this):this.empty().each(function(){1!==this.nodeType&&11!==this.nodeType&&9!==this.nodeType||(this.textContent=e)})},null,e,arguments.length)}"

Comment: @Бармалей Что это такое?

Comment: Хз, походу что-то у меня, разберусь, спасибо